# A beginner question about the return value of the C ternary operator

Tags: c, integer, printf, conditional-operator, conversion-specifier

Consider this code:

```
#define SZIE 1024

printf("%\zu",SZIE<-1?1:0);
```

It will print '0'.
This confuses me.

In my view, the signed number `-1` shoulkd be converted to `SIZE_MAX`.
The expression `1024 < SIZE_MAX` is true, so I think "1" should be printed, but no.

I tried converting explicitly:

```
printf("%zu",SIZE<(size_t)-1?1:0);
```

It prints "1", which seems correct.

Comment: `SZIE` is not typed, it's simply text that will be replaced by the number `1024` by the preprocessor. So `SZIE<-1` is `1024<-1` which is obviously false

Comment: Your ternary operator evaluates either to `0` or`1` which are both of type `int`. Your format specifier `%zu` is for arguments of type `size_t`. That does not match, causing undefined behaviour. `size_t` is likely to be larger than `int`.

Comment: Why would there be `SIZE_T_MAX` involved anywhere? There is no variable of type `size_t` in your first snippet.

Comment: `#define SIZE (1024U)`

Comment: The conversion specifier `%zu` tells `printf` to *expect* a `size_t` as the corresponding argument, but it's up to you to make sure that that argument actually does have type `size_t`.  The format string has no bearing at all on the type of the expression `SZIE<-1?1:0` or of any of the sub-expressions or constants within, nor does it cause any automatic type conversion of the `printf` arguments.

Comment: I understand now. I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Given that comparison expressions already evaluate to 1 when true and to 0 when false, this could have been formulated without mentioning the ternary operator at all. Which makes the [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615) awful.

Answer (score 3):

You defined a macro  `SZIE` (I think you mean `SIZE`) for the integer constant `1024` of the type `int`.

```
#define SZIE 1024
```

So `1024` is not less than `-1`.

Moreover as the operands have the type `int` then and the result of the conditional operator has also the type `int` and you need to use the conversion specifier `d` instead of `zu` in the call of printf.  And it seems there is a typo `\z` in the format string

```
printf("%\zu",SZIE<-1?1:0);
```

That is you need to write

```
printf("%d\n",SZIE<-1?1:0);
```

If you need to get the expected result you can write for example

```
printf("%d\n",( size_t )SZIE<-1?1:0);
```

Or it would be enough to introduce a constant of the type `unsigned int` like

```
#define SZIE 1024u
```

and write

```
printf("%d\n",SZIE<-1?1:0);
```

In this case due to the usual arithmetic conversions the expression `-1` having the type `int` will be converted to the type `unsigned int` producing a big unsigned value.

Pay attention to that independent of the condition expression of the conditional operator its result in any case has the type `int` because the second and the third operands have the type `int`. And the condition expression itself has the type `int` and yields either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`1024`, `-1` and `0` are all `int`s so the result of the operator should be `0` since `1020 < -1` is `false` and the *false* value is therefore chosen.

When you do `(size_t) -1` and convert the `int` to an unsigned type, it'll get the largest value possible for a `size_t` - which is larger than `1024` and therefore the *truth* value `1` is chosen.

Note that `%zu` is wrong in both cases since both `1` and `0` are still `int`s so the *type* of the operator is `int` and you should therefore use `%d` to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d\n",SZIE<-1?1:0);` is equvakent to

```
if(SZIE < -1) printf("%d\n", 1);
else printf("%d\n", 0);
```

As your `SZIE` is 1024 the `else` part of `if` will be executed.

Generally ternry operator:

```
(condition) ? (value_if_condition_is_true) : (value_if_condition_is_false)
```

PS Your `printf` format string is wrong.